# Choosing Correct Dates

Tags: ms-access, ms-query

Please excuse my formatting... I am working on that.

I am trying to select the correct price of a project in my query based off the appropriate effective date.

For example we have a table that has the following information

Price Table-------------------------

Item   Price   effectiveDate

- A       $0.57     1/1/17
- A       $0.72     6/1/17

Now I have a production table that contains what was produced that day and it will list out their quantity and the production for a production date.

Production Table-------------------

Item   Quantity   productionDate

- A        100       2/1/17
- A        100       7/1/17

Now when I query these I want to be able to select the appropriate price given the productionDate and effectiveDate.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (first select the highest effectiveDate lower than the productionDate, then get the price for that date):

```
SELECT preselection.Item, Price FROM  
(SELECT Production.Item, Max(effectiveDate) As MaxEffectiveDate
FROM Production INNER JOIN Price ON Price.item = Production.Item
Where Price.effectiveDate <= productionDate GROUP BY Production.Item) As preselection 
INNER JOIN Price ON Price.Item = preselection.Item 
AND Price.effectiveDate = preselection.MaxEffectiveDate
```

Comment: @James  In case you are very new to queries and SQL, the inner query (in parenthesis) can be saved as a separate query, for example as [Get Production Effective Date].  Then that saved query can be referenced in the other query like `SELECT preselection.Item, Price FROM [Get Production Effective Date] As preselection INNER JOIN Price ON Price.Item = preselection.Item AND Price.effectiveDate = preselection.MaxEffectiveDate`.  The benefit to this approach is that both queries can be separately edited and tested using the Access Design View.